# How does bcrypt keep up with Moore's law?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I have been seeing recommendations to use bcrypt to hash passwords because of its ability to keep up with Moore's Law.

Apparently the reason for this is because it would take much longer for an attacker to crack a bcrypt hash than a hash generated by a general purpose hash function like SHA256.

How is that possible? How can an algorithm be deliberately slow in spite of Moore's law?

Comment: I believe Bcrypt employs a work factor which can be ramped up to increase the cost of generating a hash as processors get faster.

Answer (score 5):

[bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is configurable with a parameter called "work factor". Internally, it will perform an operation which is similar to hashing, many times successively. The "many" is the part that can be configured, up to several billions. So, to cope with Moore's law, just crank up that setting. Another function which can be made as slow as wanted is [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (see the "iteration count" parameter).

Note that the point of making the password hashing slow is to make things difficult for the attacker, but it also mechanically makes things slow for the "honest systems" too; that's a trade-off. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage/6415#6415) (on security.stackexchange) for more details.

Comment: Your input on this question would be greatly appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479442/high-quality-simple-random-password-generator/

Answer (score 5):

An attacker will want to try all [216,553 english words](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed).

Plus another 12 bits of effort for [the common variations](http://xkcd.com/936/), which lets say gives a list of 887,001,088 (2<sup>29</sup>) possible passwords.

BCrypt takes about [4,342,912 (i.e. 2<sup>22</sup>) operations to calculate one hash (at cost=12)](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-dev/2012/05/14/1).

A core today provides about 2<sup>31</sup> cycles/sec; the state of the art is 8 = 2<sup>3</sup> cores per processor for a total of 2<sup>3</sup> * 231 = 2<sup>34</sup> cycles/sec. A server typically has 4 processors, increasing the total to 2<sup>2</sup> * 2<sup>34</sup> = 2<sup>36</sup> cycles/sec. 
2<sup>22</sup> cycles to calculate one hash * 2<sup>29</sup> possible (common) passwords = 2<sup>51</sup> cycles to run through all (common) passwords.

This means that it would take a 4-processor, octo-core, server about 2<sup>51</sup> / 2<sup>36</sup> = 2<sup>15</sup> seconds (9 hours) to run through all common passwords.

In reality my password is not common, and uses about 44-bits. 2<sup>44</sup> passwords * 2<sup>22</sup> cycles per password = 2<sup>66</sup> cycles to try all uncommon passwords. 2<sup>66</sup> / 2<sup>36</sup> cycles/second = 2<sup>30</sup> seconds (34 years) to find my password.

Moore's Law's says the processing power doubles every 18 months.

- today: 34 years to find my uncommon password
- 1.5 years: 17 years
- 3 years: 8.5 years
- 4.5: 4.25 years
- 6 years: 2.125 years
- 7.5 years: 1 year
- 9 years: 6 months
- 10.5 years: 3 months
- 12 years: 6 weeks
- 13.5 years: 3 weeks
- 15 years: 10 days
- 17.5 years: 5 days
- 19 years: 63 hours
- 20.5 years: 31 hours

That's now **bcrypt** holds up against Moore's Law.

Increase the **cost** factor from **12** to **13** and that will *double* the times involved.