# High quality, simple random password generator

Tags: python, security, random, passwords

I'm interested in creating a very simple, high (cryptographic) quality random password generator. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import os, random, string

length = 13
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

print ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
```

Comment: Are these passwords for humans or machines?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Stating that “randomness != cryptography” is just egregious in and of itself, since modern cryptography is built on randomness. Not all randomness is created equal (eg: a password selected at random from “password” and “passwords” is obviously not secure), but at its heart, cryptography == randomness.

Comment: Isn't `random.seed` a method, so `random.seed = 'random_string'` basically destroys that method and doesn't do anything?  Do you mean `random.seed('random_string')`?

Comment: `os.urandom(1024)` fetches 1024 bytes. It seems a bit excessive to me. Perhaps seeding with 16 or 32 bytes would be more appropriate.

Comment: You caused such a confusion with phrasing of that question. After reading all the answers I'm no longer sure if you wanted a more efficient way to generate a random password or if you wanted a **better** way to generate a password in general. I'm just looking for the first option and have thankfully found it at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: @AlenSiljak Yes - it's confusing. We would benefit by knowing which of the many implementations you found useful for your purposes (vs the assumption made by the top-ranked answer by Pornin re human-memorizable passwords). It would also help to know what you're looking for in a "password". From other comments of yours, it sound like you may use a password storage app like keepass. A raw unbiased bit string is good for some purposes, but on the other end of the spectrum, many web sites have a variety of very specific passwords requirements, which significantly complicate the task.

Comment: @nealmcb, if you find it beneficial - my goal was, as stated in the question, a "random password generator". In my case it is used for Flask's encryption of tokens (JWT) for web API access and, hence, my only concern is that it is random. And at pre-defined length. Therefore I was looking only for a technical solution, not a discussion on what is a good password/phrase. Yes, I'm using KeePass-like solutions exactly for that purpose. These things are keys and not worth memorizing, in my view. Not knowing a password is sometimes a safer option.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, @AlenSiljak. Which implementation here ("at the bottom of the page"?) did you end up liking here for generating JWT secrets?

Comment: @nealmcb, I ended up using Avikd's answer, which uses letters in lowercase and uppercase, numbers, and predefined symbols, at a given length. For my case this is good enough and is regenerated every time the API server is restarted. The generated value is used as secret key for JWT hashing.

Comment: @AlenSiljak Ahh - then you've got a flawed answer. I just tested that, and added a comment to note the big bias in character selection frequencies across the alphabet that Avikd used. It really is best not to use anything but the most carefully-vetted crypto code.

Comment: @nealmcb, that's why I'm here ;). Thanks for the recommendation of foudfou's implementation of Pornin's algorithm! Much appreciated. While I needed this only for a small test project, it is always a pleasure to learn something new.
Also, I see a lot of people going into discussion about pass-codes, -words, -phrases. This is very interesting but probably beyond the point of this particular question. Educational, nonetheless.

Answer (score 93):

FYI for anyone running across this question in the year 2020+. Python 3.6+ has a `secrets` module specifically for this purpose:

```
import secrets

password_length = 13
print(secrets.token_urlsafe(password_length))
```

Comment: The resulting password will have password length of `password_length * 1.3` as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe). Quoting the docs: "Return a random URL-safe text string, containing nbytes random bytes. The text is Base64 encoded, so on average each byte results in approximately 1.3 characters."

Answer (score 49):

[XKCD](http://xkcd.com/936/) has a great explanation of why **what you think** are strong passwords **aren't**.

[image: http://xkcd.com/936/]

> To anyone who understands information theory and security and is in an
>   infuriating argument with someone who does not (possibly involving
>   mixed case), I sincerely apologize. - Randall Munroe

And if you don't understand the [math behind what this illustration is explaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Entropy_as_a_measure_of_password_strength), don't try writing anything that should be cryptographically secure, because it won't be. Just put the mouse down and step away from the keyboard.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's [a post on IT Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) about this comic that Jeff recently used as an example of a great question.

Comment: That XKCD comic doesn't comes from nothing. It was based on what is true...What I have to say is that the hint of the comic was: "To anyone who understands information theory and security and is in an infuriating argument with someone who does not (possibly involving mixed case), I sincerely apologize." http://www.explainxkcd.com/2011/08/10/password-strength/
Also, LifeHacker bloged about that http://lifehacker.com/5830355/xkcd-password-generator-creates-high+security-easy+to+remember-passwords

Comment: That's what Randal was talking about when he make the commic:
[Why the password "this is fun" is 10 times more secure than "J4fS!2"](http://www.baekdal.com/tips/password-security-usability)

Comment: Lets keep comments constructive, please.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong: randomness *does* make "cryptographically strong" passwords, and the comic is pointedly contrasting a *non-random,* difficult password with a *random,* easy pass phrase. Entropy of English words is a function of dictionary size, not word length. Rather than 4.7 bits per letter, is more like 17 bits per word. It is easier for me to create a mnemonic for a sequence of medium-length root words, so suppose I create a dictionary of 2048 such words. Even if an attacker steals my list, each *randomly* chosen word still adds at least 11 bits of entropy to the pass phrase.

Comment: @erickson - do you have a reference for "[entropy is] more like 17 bits per word". I'm interested in reading about it. (I've seen entropy estimates for english that are roughly 1.2 or 1.3 bits, so I'm wondering about the 17 for a word).

Comment: @jww 17 bits is based on random selection from a dictionary of 130,000 words (roughly the number of tournament-legal Scrabble words between 5 and 11 letters long on the OWL2 list). This is just the entropy of a 130k-sided die, and can be computed exactly. An estimate of 1.2 bits per word is based on the ability to predict the next word in real English text. That's only an estimate, and will depend on the particular text. My comment was trying to point out the difference between the two cases; a mangled "troubadour" is *not* random. Drawing words from a shuffled dictionary is.

Comment: @jww As an example, consider "I ____ you ____ much!" If you were to survey a large corpus of English text, you'll find that you can predict what goes in the blanks with high probability. The blanks don't lose much information; or, in other words, the entropy of those missing words is very low. What is the probability you can correctly fill in the blanks in "aspergilli  ____ graveness ____ doable"? (They are "chawbacons" and "monogamists", in this case.) Because the missing symbols were randomly selected from a large set, their entropy is high.

Comment: @Droogans The comic doesn't show that "random words > random characters". It shows that 4 random words > 1 random word + a few random characters and tweaks in a fairly fixed format, where ">" means "has more entropy and is easier to remember". A string of random characters the same length as "correct horse battery staple" would have far more entropy than the random words.

Answer (score 49):

The difficult thing with passwords is to make them strong enough and still be able to remember them. If the password is not meant to be remembered by a human being, then it is not really a password.

You use Python's `os.urandom()`: that's good. For any practical purpose (even cryptography), the output of `os.urandom()` is indistinguishable from true alea. Then you use it as seed in `random`, which is less good: that one is a non-cryptographic PRNG, and its output may exhibit some structure which will not register in a statistical measurement tool, but might be exploited by an intelligent attacker. You should work with `os.urandom()` all along. To make things simple: choose an alphabet of length 64, e.g. letters (uppercase and lowercase), digits, and two extra punctuation characters (such as '+' and '/'). Then, for each password character, get one byte from `os.urandom()`, reduce the value modulo 64 (this is unbiased because 64 divides 256) and use the result as index in your `chars` array.

With an alphabet of length 64, you get 6 bits of entropy per character (because 2<sup>6</sup> = 64). Thus, with 13 characters, you get 78 bits of entropy. This is not ultimately strong in all cases, but already very strong (it could be defeated with a budget which will be counted in months and billions of dollars, not mere millions).

Comment: Waaait a minute... This might sound like a dumb question, but `os.urandom()` returns type `bytes`, so how can I reduce that mod 64?

Comment: Ask for one byte, then get the byte value, which is an integer in the 0 to 255 range.

Comment: But it's pretty hard to remember 13 random characters. That is actually Randall's point in the famous XKCD comic.  I'd suggest https://github.com/redacted/XKCD-password-generator using its --acrostic option to get a pattern you find even easier to remember.

Comment: For anyone else still confused, @ThomasPornin's solution would be e.g. `chars[ord(os.urandom(1)) % len(chars)]`

Comment: @ChristianBenke: note that this is unbiased because the `chars[]` array we are talking about has length 64, and 256 (the number of possible values for a byte) is a multiple of 64. If you use an array length that is not an exact divisor of 256 then the selection will be biased (some of the characters will be more probable than others).

Comment: @ThomasPornin Oh my! What one has to consider! Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: @Sean As `os.urandom` output is of type bytes, I consider `os.urandom(1)[0]` to be more pythonic, because you want "first byte of a bytes array". But note that only `ord(os.urandom(1))` works both in Python 2 & 3.

Comment: "If the password is not meant to be remembered by a human being, then it is not really a password." [citation needed]

Comment: Am I the only one that's disappointed and troubled that this lengthy explanation isn't coupled with some code? I get it, this is deliberate, but, like now we're left to the wolves? Huh.

Comment: @nealmcb, the OP **never** requested the password to be easy to remember for a human. My KeePass has no issues remembering all kinds of passwords, for that matter.

Comment: `password is not meant to be remembered by a human being, then it is not really a password` that's a semantic definition that was wrong in 2011 and is more wrong now.  In computing people will call a key a "password" if it short and text based and send with an account name for the purpose of authentication. Human memorability has been a feature of *user* password where user means "human".  But computer-computer authentication keys were historically called passwords also (rightly or wrongly).

Answer (score 13):

Just two days ago, Kragen Javier Sitaker posted a program to do this at http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2011-September/000527.html (gone now - try https://github.com/jesterpm/bin/blob/master/mkpasswd)

Generate a random, memorizable password: http://xkcd.com/936/

Example run:

kragen at inexorable:~/devel/inexorable-misc$ ./mkpass.py 5 12 Your password is "learned damage saved residential stages". That's equivalent to a 60-bit key.

That password would take 2.5e+03 CPU-years to crack on my inexpensive Celeron E1200 from 2008, assuming an offline attack on a MS-Cache hash, which is the worst password hashing algorithm in common use, slightly worse than even simple MD5.

The most common password-hashing algorithm these days is FreeBSD’s iterated MD5; cracking such a hash would take 5.2e+06 CPU-years.

But a modern GPU can crack about 250 times as fast, so that same iterated MD5 would fall in 2e+04 GPU-years.

That GPU costs about US$1.45 per day to run in 2011, so cracking the password would cost about US$3e+09.

I've started using a password generated this way in place of a 9-printable- ASCII-character random password, which is equally strong. Munroe's assertion that these passwords are much easier to memorize is correct.  However, there is still a problem: because there are many fewer bits of entropy per character (about 1.7 instead of 6.6) there is a lot of redundancy in the password, and so attacks such as the ssh timing-channel attack (the Song, Wagner, and Tian Herbivore attack, which I learned about from Bram Cohen in the Bagdad Café in the wee hours one morning, years ago) and keyboard audio recording attacks have a much better chance of capturing enough information to make the password attackable.

My countermeasure to the Herbivore attack, which works well with 9-character password but is extremely annoying with my new password, is to type the password with a half-second delay between characters, so that the timing channel does not carry much information about the actual characters used. Additionally, the lower length of the 9-character password inherently gives the Herbivore approach much less information to chew on.

Other possible countermeasures include using Emacs shell-mode, which prompts you locally for the password when it recognizes a password prompt and then sends the whole password at once, and copying and pasting the password from somewhere else.

As you'd expect, this password also takes a little while longer to type: about 6 seconds instead of about 3 seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random, itertools, os, sys

def main(argv):
    try:
        nwords = int(argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        return usage(argv[0])

    try:
        nbits = int(argv[2])
    except IndexError:
        nbits = 11

    filename = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'devel', 'wordlist')
    wordlist = read_file(filename, nbits)
    if len(wordlist) != 2**nbits:
        sys.stderr.write("%r contains only %d words, not %d.\n" %
                         (filename, len(wordlist), 2**nbits))
        return 2

    display_password(generate_password(nwords, wordlist), nwords, nbits)
    return 0

def usage(argv0):
    p = sys.stderr.write
    p("Usage: %s nwords [nbits]\n" % argv0)
    p("Generates a password of nwords words, each with nbits bits\n")
    p("of entropy, choosing words from the first entries in\n")
    p("$HOME/devel/wordlist, which should be in the same format as\n")
    p("<http://canonical.org/~kragen/sw/wordlist>, which is a text file\n")
    p("with one word per line, preceded by its frequency, most frequent\n")
    p("words first.\n")
    p("\nRecommended:\n")
    p("    %s 5 12\n" % argv0)
    p("    %s 6\n" % argv0)
    return 1

def read_file(filename, nbits):
    return [line.split()[1] for line in
            itertools.islice(open(filename), 2**nbits)]

def generate_password(nwords, wordlist):
    choice = random.SystemRandom().choice
    return ' '.join(choice(wordlist) for ii in range(nwords))

def display_password(password, nwords, nbits):
    print 'Your password is "%s".' % password
    entropy = nwords * nbits
    print "That's equivalent to a %d-bit key." % entropy
    print

    # My Celeron E1200
    # (<http://ark.intel.com/products/34440/Intel-Celeron-Processor-E1200-(512K-Cache-1_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)>)
    # was released on January 20, 2008.  Running it in 32-bit mode,
    # john --test (<http://www.openwall.com/john/>) reports that it
    # can do 7303000 MD5 operations per second, but I’m pretty sure
    # that’s a single-core number (I don’t think John is
    # multithreaded) on a dual-core processor.
    t = years(entropy, 7303000 * 2)
    print "That password would take %.2g CPU-years to crack" % t
    print "on my inexpensive Celeron E1200 from 2008,"
    print "assuming an offline attack on a MS-Cache hash,"
    print "which is the worst password hashing algorithm in common use,"
    print "slightly worse than even simple MD5."
    print

    t = years(entropy, 3539 * 2)
    print "The most common password-hashing algorithm these days is FreeBSD’s"
    print "iterated MD5; cracking such a hash would take %.2g CPU-years." % t
    print

    # (As it happens, my own machines use Drepper’s SHA-2-based
    # hashing algorithm that was developed to replace the one
    # mentioned above; I am assuming that it’s at least as slow as the
    # MD5-crypt.)

    # <https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison> says a
    # Core 2 Duo U7600 can do 1.1 Mhash/s (of Bitcoin) at a 1.2GHz
    # clock with one thread.  The Celeron in my machine that I
    # benchmarked is basically a Core 2 Duo with a smaller cache, so
    # I’m going to assume that it could probably do about 1.5Mhash/s.
    # All common password-hashing algorithms (the ones mentioned
    # above, the others implemented in John, and bcrypt, but not
    # scrypt) use very little memory and, I believe, should scale on
    # GPUs comparably to the SHA-256 used in Bitcoin.

    # The same mining-hardware comparison says a Radeon 5870 card can
    # do 393.46 Mhash/s for US$350.

    print "But a modern GPU can crack about 250 times as fast,"
    print "so that same iterated MD5 would fall in %.1g GPU-years." % (t / 250)
    print

    # Suppose we depreciate the video card by Moore’s law,
    # i.e. halving in value every 18 months.  That's a loss of about
    # 0.13% in value every day; at US$350, that’s about 44¢ per day,
    # or US$160 per GPU-year.  If someone wanted your password as
    # quickly as possible, they could distribute the cracking job
    # across a network of millions of these cards.  The cards
    # additionally use about 200 watts of power, which at 16¢/kWh
    # works out to 77¢ per day.  If we assume an additional 20%
    # overhead, that’s US$1.45/day or US$529/GPU-year.
    cost_per_day = 1.45
    cost_per_crack = cost_per_day * 365 * t
    print "That GPU costs about US$%.2f per day to run in 2011," % cost_per_day
    print "so cracking the password would cost about US$%.1g." % cost_per_crack

def years(entropy, crypts_per_second):
    return float(2**entropy) / crypts_per_second / 86400 / 365.2422

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: could you put `generate_password()` (with `random.SystemRandom()`) at the top of your answer? It might help [people who landed here searching for: "python password generator"](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/36097)

Answer (score 11):

implementing @Thomas Pornin solution

```
import M2Crypto
import string

def random_password(length=10):
    chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
    password = ''
    for i in range(length):
        password += chars[ord(M2Crypto.m2.rand_bytes(1)) % len(chars)]
    return password
```

Comment: you could simply use os.urandom(1) (cryptographically strong) and remove the dependency from M2Crypto

Comment: Using `% len(chars)` this way has a slight bias towards the first 8 characters in `chars`. Each of these letters would appear 1.95% of the time, compared to 1.56% for the other characters.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question was posted back in 2011, but for those coming to it now in 2014 and beyond, I have one thing to say: RESIST THE URGE TO REINVENT THE WHEEL.

In these situations your best bet is to search for open-source software, e.g., constrain your search to github results. By far the best thing I've found:

**https://github.com/redacted/XKCD-password-generator**

Comment: Agreed.  There are some nice options in the github version, e.g. to print out how much entropy your password has, and to let you provide an "acrostic" so that the first character of each word matches a word of your choice.

Comment: I'm interested in "classical" random string passwords though, if I wanted passphrase generation I would look for that. (what I am doing isn't for humans to remember)

Answer (score 7):

You can't trust python's pseudo random number generator when generating a password. It is not necessarily cryptographically random. You are seeding the pseudo random number generator from `os.urandom` which is a good start. But then you depend on python's generator after that.

A better choice would be the [`random.SystemRandom()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) class which takes random numbers from the same source as `urandom`. According to the python documentation that should be good enough for cryptographic use. The `SystemRandom` class gives you everything that the main random class does but you don't need to worry about the pseudorandomness.

Example code using random.SystemRandom (for Python 3):

```
import random, string
length = 13
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'

rnd = random.SystemRandom()
print(''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
```

Note: Your mileage may vary - the Python Documentation says that random.SystemRandom availability varies by operating system.

Comment: The Linux PRNG (`/dev/urandom`) is considered cryptographically secure. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key.

Comment: I think you are getting your concepts mixed up here. In a deterministic computer there is no true randomness; everything (including `/dev/urandom`) is pseudo random unless you have specialized hardware.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ +1 A consumer can do this with a webcam or CCD in a pitch black environment (see [`LavaRnd`](http://www.lavarnd.org/what/how-it-works.html)).

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ, There a few source of randomness that your computer does collect. However, I was wrong, urandom mixes that with a pseudorandom number generator. Nevertheless, using SystemRandom is a good idea because you can be sure its cryptographically random whereas the same isn't neccesairly true of the python random number generator.

Answer (score 3):

Considering your comment,

> I just need to be able to generate passwords that are more secure than the ones I would come up with in my head.

it seems you want to use your program to generate passwords, rather than just writing it as an exercise. It is preferable to use an existing implementation, because if you make a mistake, the output might be compromised. Read about [random number generator attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator_attack); in particular, a well-known RNG bug in Debian exposed people's SSL private keys.

So instead, consider using [`pwgen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen). It provides several options, which you should choose depending on what you plan to use the passwords for.

Comment: The Debian vulnerability was an implementation error. Generally, `/dev/urando` & `/dev/random` are non-distinguishable from true random (except for the first 10 minutes or so after system boot)

Answer (score 3):

Implenting @Thomas Pornin solution (can't comment @Yossi inexact answer):

```py
import string, os
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '+/'
assert 256 % len(chars) == 0  # non-biased later modulo
PWD_LEN = 16
print(''.join(chars[c % len(chars)] for c in os.urandom(PWD_LEN)))
```

**UPDATED** for python3 thank to Stephan Lukits

Comment: In python 3.8 'string.ascii_letters' needs to be used and iterating over bytes already gives integers thus 'orc(c)' will fail and 'c' instead will work.

Answer (score 3):

Base64 let us encode binary data in a human readable/writable mode with no data loss.

```
import os
random_bytes=os.urandom(12)
secret=random_bytes.encode("base64")
```

Comment: Always encourage a small bit of text in answers to introduce code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

I love linguistics, in my approach I create memorable pseudo words with high level of entropy by alternating consonants & vowels.

- Not susceptible to dictionary attacks
- Pronounceable and therefore good chance to be
  memorable
- Short passwords with decent strength
- Optional parameter to add a random digit for compatibility (less memorable, but conforms to apps built with the old password security thinking, e.g. requiring a digit)

Python code:

```
import random
import string


def make_pseudo_word(syllables=5, add_number=False):
    """Create decent memorable passwords.

    Alternate random consonants & vowels
    """
    rnd = random.SystemRandom()
    s = string.ascii_lowercase
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    consonants = ''.join([x for x in s if x not in vowels])
    pwd = ''.join([rnd.choice(consonants) + rnd.choice(vowels)
               for x in range(syllables)]).title()
    if add_number:
        pwd += str(rnd.choice(range(10)))
    return pwd


>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=5)
'Bidedatuci'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=5)
'Fobumehura'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=5)
'Seganiwasi'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=4)
'Dokibiqa'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=4)
'Lapoxuho'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=4)
'Qodepira'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=3)
'Minavo'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=3)
'Fiqone'
>>> make_pseudo_word(syllables=3)
'Wiwohi'
```

Cons:

- for Latin and Germanic language speakers and those familiar with English
- one should use vowels and consonants of the language predominant with the application users or focus group and tune

Answer (score 2):

It is easy :)

```
def codegenerator():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    pw_length = 8
    mypw = ""

    for i in range(pw_length):
        next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
        mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]
    return mypw
```

and the do:

```
print codegenerator()
```

Thanks http://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 2):

```
import random


r = random.SystemRandom()


def generate_password(words, top=2000, k=4, numbers=None, characters=None,
                      first_upper=True):
    """Return a random password based on a sorted word list."""
    elements = r.sample(words[:top], k)

    if numbers:
        elements.insert(r.randint(1, len(elements)), r.choice(numbers))
    if characters:
        elements.insert(r.randint(1, len(elements)), r.choice(characters))
    if first_upper:
        elements[0] = elements[0].title()

    return ''.join(elements)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('./google-10000-english-usa.txt') as f:
        words = [w.strip() for w in f]
    print(generate_password(words, numbers='0123456789', characters='!@#$%'))
```

- Generates passwords that you can remember
- Uses `os.urandom()`
- Handles real-world rules like adding numbers, uppercase, characters.

Sure it can be improved, but this is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

That way works.  It is perfectly fine.  If you had additional rules, such as excluding dictionary words, then you may want to include those filters as well, but the likelihood of randomly generating a dictionary word with that setup is extremely small.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your implementation:

```
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
```

This does not seed the random number generator; it replaces the `seed` function with a bytestring. You need to call `seed`, like, `random.seed(…)`.

```
print ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
```

Python's default PRNG is a Mersenne Twister, which is not a cryptographically strong PRNG, so I'm wary of using it for cryptographic purposes. The `random` module includes `random.SystemRandom`, which on at least most *nix systems, should use a CSPRNG. *However*,

```
random.choice(chars)
```

…is implemented as…

```
def choice(self, seq):
    """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
```

…in *Python 2*. Unfortunately, `self.random` here is a C function, so this gets hard to see; the code smell here is that this code almost certainly doesn't choose uniformly. The code has completely changed in Python 3, and does a much better job of ensuring uniformity. The Python 3 docs for `randrange` note,

> Changed in version 3.2: `randrange()` is more sophisticated about producing equally distributed values. Formerly it used a style like `int(random()*n)` which could produce slightly uneven distributions.

`randrange` and `choice` both call the same method (`_randbelow`) under the hood.

In Python 3, `choice` is fine; in Python 2, it only comes *close* to a uniform distribution, but does not guarantee it. Since this is crypto, I lean on the "take no chances" side of the fence, and would like to have that guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Built my own CLI answer to the topic at hand (full source code at the following URL):

http://0netenv.blogspot.com/2016/08/password-generator-with-argparse.html

Wrote a password generator using argparse.
Hope this helps someone (either building a password generator or using argparse)!

Either way, it was fun to build!

```
$ ./pwgen.py -h
usage: pwgen.py [-h] [-c COUNT] [-a] [-l] [-n] [-s] [-u] [-p]

 Create a random password
 Special characters, numbers, UPPERCASE -"Oscar",
 and lowercase -"lima" to avoid confusion.
 Default options (no arguments): -c 16 -a
                Enjoy! --0NetEnv@gmail.com

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -c COUNT, --count COUNT
                        password length
  -a, --all             same as -l -n -s -u
  -l, --lower           include lowercase characters
  -n, --number          include 0-9
  -s, --special         include special characters
  -u, --upper           include uppercase characters
  -p, --license         print license and exit
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

license = """
#  pwgen -- the pseudo-random password generator 
#
#  This software is distributed under the MIT license.
#    
#  The MIT License (MIT)
#
#  Copyright (c) 2016 0NetEnv 0netenv@gmail.com
#  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any 
#  person obtaining a copy of this software and associated 
#  documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the 
#  Software without restriction, including without 
#  limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, 
#  publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies 
#  of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the 
#  Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following 
#  conditions:
#
#  The above copyright notice and this permission notice 
#  shall be included in all copies or substantial portions 
#  of the Software.
#
#  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF 
#  ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED 
#  TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
#  PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT 
#  SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY 
#  CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION 
#  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR 
#  IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER 
#  DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#  
#  NOTE:
#  This software was tested on Slackware 14.2, Raspbian, & 
#  Mac OS X 10.11
#
"""

import string
import random
import sys
# first time using argparse library
import argparse
# wanted to change the formatting of the help menu a little bit, so used RawTextHelpFormatter directly
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter

typo = ''
c = 16
counter = 0
line = '-' * 40

# CREATE FUNCTION for PWGEN
def pwgen(z, t):
    # EMPTY SET OF CHARACTERS
    charsset = ''
    # UPPERCASE -"O"
    U = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    # lowercase -"l"
    L = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    N = '0123456789'
    S = '!@#$%^&*?<>'

    # make sure we're using an integer, not a char/string
    z = int(z)
    for type in t:
        if 'u' in t:
            charsset = charsset + U
        if 'l' in t:
            charsset = charsset + L
        if 'n' in t:
            charsset = charsset + N
        if 's' in t:
            charsset = charsset + S
        if 'a' == t:
            charsset = charsset + U + L + N + S

    return ''.join(random.choice(charsset) for _ in range(0, int(z)))

# GET ARGUMENTS using ARGPARSE
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='\n Create a random password\n\
 Special characters, numbers, UPPERCASE -"Oscar",\n\
 and lowercase -"lima" to avoid confusion.\n\
 Default options (no arguments): -c 16 -a\n\
 \t\tEnjoy! --0NetEnv@gmail.com', formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--count", dest="count", action="store", help="password length")
parser.add_argument("-a", "--all", help="same as -l -n -s -u", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-l", "--lower", help="include lowercase characters", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", help="include 0-9", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--special", help="include special characters", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-u", "--upper", help="include uppercase characters", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--license", help="print license and exit", action="store_true")

# COLLECT ARGPARSE RESULTS
results = args = parser.parse_args()

# CHECK RESULTS
# Check that a length was given.
# If not, gripe and exit.
if args.count == '0':
    print ("Input error:\nCannot create a zero length password.\nExiting")
    exit (0)
# check character results and add to counter if 
# selection is made.
if args.lower:
    typo = typo + 'l'
    counter = counter + 1
    #print "lower"
if args.number:
    typo = typo + 'n'
    counter = counter + 1
    #print "number"
if args.special:
    typo = typo + 's'
    counter = counter + 1
    #print "special"
if args.upper:
    typo = typo + 'u'
    counter = counter + 1
    #print "upper"
if args.all:
    typo = 'a'
    counter = counter + 1
    #print "all"
if args.license:
    print (license)
    exit (1)

# CHECK COUNTER
# Check our counter and see if we used any command line 
# options. We don't want to error out.
# try it gracefully. If no arguments are given, 
# use defaults and tell the user.
# args.count comes from argparse and by default requires
# an input to '-c'. We want to get around that for the 
# sake of convenience.
# Without further adieu, here's our if statement:
if args.count:
    if counter == 0:
        typo = 'a'
        print ("defaulting to '--all'")
    print (line)
    print (pwgen(results.count,typo))
else:
    if counter == 0:
        typo = 'a'
        print ("defaulting to '--count 16 --all'")
    print (line)
    print (pwgen(c,typo))
print (line)
#print typo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation (python 2; would require some minor rewrites to get it working in 3) that is much faster than OJW's, which seems to loop through the dictionary for each word, despite the comment/implication to the contrary. Timing of OJW's script on my machine, with an 80,000 IOP SSD:

```
real    0m3.264s
user    0m1.768s
sys     0m1.444s
```

The following script loads the whole dictionary into a list, then picks words based on a random selection of the index value, using OJW's regex for filtering.

This also generates 10 passphrase sets, allows passing command-line parameters to adjust the number of words, and adds number and symbol padding (also adjustable length).

Sample times for this script:

```
real    0m0.289s
user    0m0.176s
sys     0m0.108s
```

Usage: xkcdpass-mod.py 2 4 (for example; these are the default values).

It prints spaces in the output for easy reading, although I've almost never encountered an online service that allows using them, so I would just ignore them. This could definitely be cleaned up with argparse or getopt and allowing switches for including spaces or not, including/excluding symbols, capitals, etc., plus some additional refactoring, but I haven't gotten to that yet. So, without further ado:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Copyright AMH, 2013; dedicated to public domain.
import os, re, sys, random
from sys import argv

def getargs():
    if len(argv) == 3:
        numwords = argv[1]
        numpads = argv[2]
        return(numwords, numpads)
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        numwords = argv[1]
        numpads = 4
        return (numwords, numpads)
    else:
        numwords = 2
        numpads = 4
        return (numwords, numpads)

def dicopen(dictionary="/usr/share/dict/american-english"):
    f = open(dictionary, "r")
    dic = f.readlines()
    return dic

def genPassword(numwords, numpads):
    r = random.SystemRandom()
    pads = '0123456789!@#$%^&*()'
    padding = []
    words = dicopen()
    wordlist = []
    for i in range (0,int(numpads)):
        padding.append(pads[r.randint(0,len(pads)-1)])
    #initialize counter for only adding filtered words to passphrase
    j = 0
    while (j < int(numwords)):
        inclusion_criteria = re.compile('^[a-z]{5,10}$')
        #Select a random number, then pull the word at that index value, rather than looping through the dictionary for each word
        current_word = words[r.randint(0,len(words)-1)].strip()
        #Only append matching words
        if inclusion_criteria.match(current_word):
            wordlist.append(current_word)
            j += 1
        else:
        #Ignore non-matching words
            pass
    return(" ".join(wordlist)+' '+''.join(padding))

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    for i in range (1,11):
       print "item "+str(i)+"\n"+genPassword(getargs()[0], getargs()[1])
```

Sample output:

```
[✗]─[user@machine]─[~/bin]
└──╼ xkcdpass-mod.py
item 1
digress basketball )%^)
item 2
graves giant &118
item 3
impelled maniacs ^@%1
```

And going for the full "correct horse battery staple" (CHBS), no padding:

```
┌─[user@machine]─[~/bin]
└──╼ xkcdpass-mod.py 4 0
item 1
superseded warred nighthawk rotary 
item 2
idealize chirruping gabbing vegan 
item 3
wriggling contestant hiccoughs instanced
```

According to https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm, for all practical purposes, assuming 100 trillion guesses per second (i.e., 100 TH/s) the shorter version would take about 50-60 million centuries to crack; the full CHBS = 1.24 hundred trillion trillion centuries; adding padding to that, 15.51 trillion trillion trillion centuries.

Even enlisting the entire Bitcoin mining network (~2500 TH/s as of this writing), the short version would still likely take 250-300 million years to break, which is probably secure enough for most purposes.

Comment: Your estimate of "50-60 million centuries to crack" the passphrase "graves giant &118" (apparently) is a huge mistake.  You must assume (as Randall did) that the attacker is generating guesses the same way you are - by picking random words from the dictionary.  Randall calculates 44 bits of entropy even for 4 words.  Also, taking an extra 3 seconds to run a program like this hardly matters.

Comment: And your pads are hard to remember but easy to crack since there are only 20 possibilities for each character (less than a lower case letter of the alphabet!), so only about 4 bits of entropy each.  Given your cracking speed assumption, cracking a 4-word password like Randall's with 44 bits of entropy would take less than a second, and cracking one like your 2-word example plus 4 random pads would be far easier (only about 22+4*4 = 38 bits of entropy).

Answer (score 0):

```
import uuid
print('Your new password is: {0}').format(uuid.uuid4())
```

Comment: I'm not confident that uuid uses random generator that is cryptographically secure. A reference would be a must.

Comment: The implementation of uuid4 is operating system dependent. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/uuid.py#L463

Answer (score 0):

A little bit off topic, but I made this, using also TKinter. Hope it can helps:

```
import os, random, string
from tkinter import *

def createPwd():
    try:
        length = int(e1.get())
    except ValueError:
        return
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()?\/'
    random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
    e2.config(state=NORMAL)
    e2.delete(0,'end')
    e2.insert(0,''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
    e2.config(state="readonly")

mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.title('Password generator')

mainWindow.resizable(0,0)

f0 = Frame(mainWindow)

f0.pack(side=TOP,pady=5,padx=5,fill=X,expand=1)

Label(f0,text="Length: ",anchor=E).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)

e1 = Entry(f0)
e1.insert(0,'12')
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)

btn = Button(f0,text="Generate")
btn['command'] = lambda: createPwd()
btn.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=1,padx=10,ipadx=10)

Label(f0,text="Generated password: ",anchor=E).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E)
e2 = Entry(f0)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)

createPwd()

#starting main window
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple small program addressed to people whome can't figure out a secure passwords for there own public accounts.

Just run the program on a command console and pass in a bunch of letters that seems familiar to you, and it will generate a sequence of symbols based on what you've inserted.

of course, the program does not support multiple sequences generation.

You can download the code from my github pull: https://github.com/abdechahidely/python_password_generator

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits, punctuation
from random import randint, choice, shuffle
from math   import ceil
from re     import finditer

lower_cases  = ascii_lowercase
upper_cases  = ascii_uppercase
lower_upper  = dict(zip(lower_cases, upper_cases))
upper_lower  = dict(zip(upper_cases, lower_cases))
punctuations = '#$%&@!?.'
space        = ' '

class PunctOrDigit():

    def __init__(self, number_of_punctuations, number_of_digits):
        self.puncts = number_of_punctuations
        self.digits = number_of_digits
        self.dupl_puncts = self.puncts
        self.dupl_digits = self.digits

    def PorD(self):
        symbol_type = choice('pd')
        if symbol_type == 'p':
            if self.puncts == 0:
                return 'd'
            else:
                self.puncts -= 1
                return symbol_type
        if symbol_type == 'd':
            if self.digits == 0:
                return 'p'
            else:
                self.digits -= 1
                return symbol_type

    def reset(self):
        self.puncts = self.dupl_puncts
        self.digits = self.dupl_digits

def is_empty(text):
    for symbol in text:
        if symbol != space:
            return False
    return True

def contain_unauthorized_symbols(text):
    for symbol in text:
        if symbol in punctuation or symbol in digits:
            return True
    return False

def user_input():
    user_input = input('-- Sentence to transform: ')
    while is_empty(user_input) or len(user_input) < 8 or contain_unauthorized_symbols(user_input):
        user_input = input('-- Sentence to transform: ')
    return user_input

def number_of_punctuations(text):
    return ceil(len(text) / 2) - 3

def number_of_digits(text):
    return ceil(len(text) / 2) - 2

def total_symbols(text):
    return (number_of_digits(text) + number_of_punctuations(text), 
            number_of_punctuations(text),
            number_of_digits(text))

def positions_to_change(text):
    pos_objct = PunctOrDigit(number_of_punctuations(text), number_of_digits(text))
    positions = {}
    while len(positions) < total_symbols(text)[0]:
        i = randint(0,len(text)-1)
        while i in positions:
            i = randint(0,len(text)-1)
        positions[i] = pos_objct.PorD()
    pos_objct.reset()
    return positions

def random_switch(letter):
    if letter in lower_cases:
        switch_or_pass = choice('sp')
        if switch_or_pass == 's': return lower_upper[letter]
        else:                     return letter
    if letter in upper_cases:
        switch_or_pass = choice('sp')
        if switch_or_pass == 's': return upper_lower[letter]
        else:                     return letter

def repeated(text):
    reps = {}
    for letter in set(list(text)):
        indexs = [w.start() for w in finditer(letter, text)]
        if letter != ' ':
            if len(indexs) != 1:
                reps[letter] = indexs
    return reps

def not_repeated(text):
    reps = {}
    for letter in set(list(text)):
        indexs = [w.start() for w in finditer(letter, text)]
        if letter != ' ':
            if len(indexs) == 1:
                reps[letter] = indexs
    return reps

def generator(text, positions_to_change):
    rep     = repeated(text)
    not_rep = not_repeated(text)
    text    = list(text)

    for x in text:
        x_pos = text.index(x)
        if x not in positions_to_change:
            text[x_pos] = random_switch(x)

    for x in rep:
        for pos in rep[x]:
            if pos in positions_to_change:
                if positions_to_change[pos] == 'p':
                    shuffle(list(punctuations))
                    text[pos] = choice(punctuations)
                if positions_to_change[pos] == 'd':
                    shuffle(list(digits))
                    text[pos] = choice(digits)
    for x in not_rep:
        for pos in not_rep[x]:
            if pos in positions_to_change:
                if positions_to_change[pos] == 'p':
                    shuffle(list(punctuations))
                    text[pos] = choice(punctuations)
                if positions_to_change[pos] == 'd':
                    shuffle(list(digits))
                    text[pos] = choice(digits)

    text = ''.join(text)
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = user_input()
    print(generator(x, positions_to_change(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my random password generator after researching this topic:

```
`import os, random, string
   #Generate Random Password
   UPP = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
   LOW1 = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
   LOW2 = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
   LOW3 = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
   DIG1 = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
   DIG2 = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
   DIG3 = random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
   SPEC = random.SystemRandom().choice('!@#$%^&*()')
   PWD = None
   PWD = UPP + LOW1 + LOW2 + LOW3 + DIG1 + DIG2 + DIG3 + SPEC
   PWD = ''.join(random.sample(PWD,len(PWD)))
   print(PWD)`
```

This will generate a random password with 1 random uppercase letter, 3 random lowercase letters, 3 random digits, and 1 random special character--this can be adjusted as needed. Then it combines each random character and creates a random order. I don't know if this is considered "high quality", but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on @Thomas Pornin's answer (Updated)

```
import os, string

def get_pass(password_len=12):
  new_password=None
  symbols='+!'
  chars=string.ascii_lowercase+\
        string.ascii_uppercase+\
        string.digits+\
        symbols

  while new_password is None or \
        new_password[0] in string.digits or \
        new_password[0] in symbols:
     new_password=''.join([chars[ord(os.urandom(1)) % len(chars)] \
                             for i in range(password_len)])
  return new_password

print(get_pass())
```

This function returns a random password (without a number or a symbol in beginning of the password).

Comment: This code is deeply flawed, suffering from the same bias problem that Pornin talks about because the `chars` list length is 69 chars, not 64. The characters preceeding 'A' show up only about 75% as often as the rest. See instead the answer by @foudfou.
In addition, it doesn't quite work at all: the last line should be `print(get_pass())`

Answer (score 0):

I just recently started learning python and this is something I wrote today. Hope this helps.

```
import random

characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^()}{/<>'
print('Password Length: ')
passwordLength = int(input())
password = ''

for i in range(passwordLength):
    password += random.choice(characters)
print(password)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
"""
This code below in any shape or form is owned by A.S Gallery 

This code is the asnwer for Password Generator quiz - CodeHs 
This code works 100%
Have fun exploring !!!

"""

# Imports 
import random
import time
print "Hi !!!"
password_output = "this is your new password : "
ask_name = input("Enter your Name : ")
greetings_name = "Hi "+ str(ask_name) + "!!! "
print greetings_name
print "Now we will make your new password using the ULTIMATE password generator !!!"
time.sleep(8)
print "Our password generator will give you multiple choices, you can choose any password generator you want !!! "
time.sleep(8)
print "You can choose if you want a strong password or a weak password !! (strong recommended) "
time.sleep(8)
print "You can also make your own password, to make your own password type own !!! "
time.sleep(8)
print "If you want to choose strong type strong, if weak then type weak !!! "
time.sleep(8)




# Example:
# Returns random number within and including 0 and 10.
def strong_password():
    user_input = int(input("Enter a number : "))
    print type(user_input)
    time.sleep(3)
    # calculate_input = user_input * user_input
    calculate_types = input("Do you want to add, multiply or mod the numbers : ")
    time.sleep(3)
    if calculate_types == "add":
        calculate_input = user_input + user_input
    elif calculate_types == "multiply" :
        calculate_input = user_input * user_input
    elif calculate_types == "mod":
        calculate_input = user_input & user_input 
    else:
        print "Check your spelling and try again :( "

    # Random element in a string
    time.sleep(4)
    want_symbols = input("Do you want symbols ?(Y/N) : ")
    time.sleep(4)
    random_element = random.choice('abcdefg345')
    if want_symbols == "Y":
        random_element2 = random.choice('@#()@*($*(@)(*^()*()(#$)*@#)*((@*()@*#)(*)@*($*(%#*)#(*@@_!_()(')
    elif want_symbols == "N":
        random_element2 = random.choice('29371294203712492703740182903820498201381204AKSJFKSHEHJKFJAODL')
    random_element3 = random.choice('abcdefghiiasudasdjsiasdhwudagsjdgaskdjsafgjasj')
    random_element4 = random.choice('abcdefghijsdhjaskdhkasjdhakdjhaskdasjdhakjsd')
    random_element5 = random.choice('abcdefghijsdhsakjdhsajdldasjdasdjasldas')
    random_elements6 = random.choice('129389230928308290382109830293943827492347')
    random_elements7 = random.choice('2473285473q9mdnuwyr8KSDJKDSJKL932uc3487389473289479h3289wjdi94802w')
    random_elements8 = random.choice('AKDJKAJDKJIKJDUIFHSJHUFRUDIJFDKLDJKDJLJFKLJKLDJLDJKLDJLDJLSKJDKLJDLJDKSLJD')


    time.sleep(8)

    print str(ask_name) + " " + str(password_output) + str(calculate_input) + str(random_element) + str(random_element2) + str(random_element3) + str(random_element4) + str(random_element5) + str(random_elements6) + str(random_elements7) + str(random_elements8)

def weak_password():
    user_input = int(input("Enter a number : "))
    print type(user_input)
    time.sleep(3)
    # calculate_input = user_input * user_input
    calculate_types = input("Do you want to add, multiply or mod the numbers : ")
    time.sleep(3)
    if calculate_types == "add":
        calculate_input = user_input + user_input
    elif calculate_types == "multiply" :
        calculate_input = user_input * user_input
    elif calculate_types == "mod":
        calculate_input = user_input & user_input 
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        print "Check your spelling and try again :( "

    # Random element in a string


    random_ness = random.choice("ABCDEFGHI*(#*#$()#*$)(E)(UWIJEDSH(*#U$()UDSLKH)UW*)$(*&#*(YE(*DY#*YUHSLDF:LKDDSDK")
    my_tuple = (calculate_input, random_ness, user_input, ask_name)
    new_tuple = my_tuple[1] 
    new_tuple1 = my_tuple[2]
    new_tuple2 = my_tuple[3]
    time.sleep(7)
    print str(ask_name) + str(password_output) + str(new_tuple) + str(new_tuple1) + str(new_tuple2) 

def own_password():
    my_list = []
    ask_times = int(input("How many characters do you want ? (between 1 - 8) : "))
    time.sleep(10)
    if ask_times > 8:
        print "Invalid Request"
    elif ask_times < 1:
        print "Invalid Request"
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "You CANNOT include symbols or numbers in this option !!! "
        for i in range(ask_times):
            user_ask = input("Enter the character: ")
            time.sleep(0.6)
            my_list.append(user_ask)
        own_password =  "".join(map(str,my_list))
        time.sleep(4)
        print "Your own password is : " + own_password




strong_pass = input("Do you want a strong password or a weak one or make your own password !! ? : ")
if strong_pass == "strong":
    strong_password()
elif strong_pass == "weak":
    weak_password()
elif strong_pass == "own":
    own_password()
else :
    print "Invalid Request"

time.sleep(3)
print "Congrats, on creating your best password !!! I belived you used strong password generator because its the BEST !!"
time.sleep(7)
print "If not, no problem just restart the program and type strong when prompted !!! "
time.sleep(6)
print "Have a nice day !"
```

This code is the answer for CodeHs Quiz too (if you had any ) !!!

Answer (score -3):

This is more for fun than anything.
Scores favorably in passwordmeter.com but impossible to remember.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts (33..126).map{|x| ('a'..'z').include?(x.chr.downcase) ?
                       (0..9).to_a.shuffle[0].to_s + x.chr :
                       x.chr}.uniq.shuffle[0..41].join[0..41]
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, no amatuer hacker is going to be cracking that password. Now, after this I recommend continuing on your random password generator project and make a UI or GUI interface either with Tkinter or Flask so others can use it. For example, I found this nice little project just by searching, 'password generator python UI'. https://passwordgenerator.pythonanywhere.com/

Maybe you'd like to make something similar to above? Its a good skill to know how to implement python into web development.

Good luck.

Peace out