# Generating random password into input with input length using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="pgenerate">
<input type="text" size=18 name="output">
<input type="button" value="Generate Password" ><br />
<b>Password Length:</b> <input type="text" name="thelength" size=3 value="7">
</form>
```

How can i make a random password generator that will generate password inside an input you can use in you projects or systems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random password string with requirements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719570/generate-random-password-string-with-requirements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var keylist="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789"
var temp=''
 
function generatepass(plength){
temp=''
for (i=0;i<plength;i++)
temp+=keylist.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*keylist.length))
return temp
}
 
function populateform(enterlength){
document.pgenerate.output.value=generatepass(enterlength)
}
```

```html
<form name="pgenerate">
<input type="text" size=18 name="output">
<input type="button" value="Generate Password" onClick="populateform(this.form.thelength.value)"><br />
<b>Password Length:</b> <input type="text" name="thelength" size=3 value="7">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Check out this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-password which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pure JS solution:

```js
function generateRandomPassword (passwordLength) {
    var outputPassword = "";
    var allPossibleChars  = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        outputPassword += allPossibleChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * allPossibleChars.length));
    }
    return outputPassword;
}
```

```html
<form name="pgenerate">
<input type="text" size=18 id="output" name="output">
<input type="button" value="Generate Password" onclick="document.getElementById('output').value = generateRandomPassword(document.getElementById('thelength').value);"><br />
<b>Password Length:</b> <input type="text" id="thelength" name="thelength" size=3 value="7">
</form>
```

If you want to add more possible chars simply update `allPossibleChars`.