# Add crypto-browserify to Gatsby project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, stripe-payments, gatsby

I want to add use-shopping-cart (https://useshoppingcart.com/) to my Gatsby project.
When I try to use it I get this error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules 
by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a
polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto":
require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

How can I add `crypto-browserify` to gatsby? as a plugin inside of `gatsby-config.js`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This kind of issue (`BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js...`) relies on the fact that [webpack has removed polyfills in their new `v5` version](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#automatic-nodejs-polyfills-removed), which is a needed dependency of `use-shopping-cart`.

It should be fixed by installing `crypto-browserify` (by `npm i crypto-browserify`) and adding the following fallback to webpack's overriding configuration, in your `gatsby-node.js`, [`onCreateWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/) API should work:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
   resolve: {
      fallback: {
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
   resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "crypto": false
      },
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to do `crypto` instead of `path` in the solution above, but it worked! Thank you so much!