# Generate Secure Password in Gatsby with Crypto API

Tags: reactjs, cryptojs

I'm attempting to generate a random password for users created through my project. Per an answer, I plugged in the following formula:

```
const generatePassword = () => {
    const crypto = require("crypto");
    return Array(12)
    .fill("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    .map(function (x) {
        let int = crypto.randomBytes(4, function(ex, buf) {
            var hex = buf.toString('hex');
            var myInt32 = parseInt(hex, 16);
        });
        return x[int % x.length];
    })
    .join("");
}
```

I get the following error `Can't resolve 'crypto' in [PROJECT]` and it gives me instructions to add a fallback via two methods:

```
if you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

I have no idea what any of that means but [some helpful folks on this site do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67333737/add-crypto-browserify-to-gatsby-project) so I plug in the following to my node.js

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "crypto": false
      },
    },
  });
};
```

I run `gatsby develop` again, it loads the site successfully, but I am greeted with an error on the page, progress! `crypto.randomBytes is not a function`. So I try the polyfill solution suggessted earlier.

I install `crypto-browserify` and update the fallback like so:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
   actions.setWebpackConfig({
     resolve: {
       fallback: {
         crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
       },
     },
  });
};
```

I run `gatsby develop` again and get an error in the terminal:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '[PROJECT]'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

cool, another node module i can install and some settings to copy pasta. It should surely work after this. NOPE!

New error drop: `process is not defined` Installing yet another npm package doesn't remedy the issue so I'm pretty tapped out at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I [found another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566188/node-js-crypto-randombytes-is-not-a-function) that doesn't involve a bunch of node modules not supported by gatsby, but rather a simple import:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

const generatePassword = () => {
  return nanoid(12);
}
```

I'm unsure about the security of `nanoid` but it's better than mathRandom since `crypto` seems like a no go.