# How can I create an aphabets array from which random uppercase & lowercase alphabets get pulled?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create an array from which random uppercase and lowercase alphabets can be used to generate a password. Could you tell me how to create such an array and add Math.random() to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript

Comment: This answer can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719570/generate-random-password-string-with-requirements-in-javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Users Marius and Mina commented on your question suggesting the answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719570/generate-random-password-string-with-requirements-in-javascript) -- which are valid and versatile answers. As an alternative, the following function returns a string of a fixed length containing random uppercase and lowercase letters -- without the use of a long string literal containing the alphabet:

```js
function generateCode(length) {
 var code = '';
 for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var character = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*26)+97);
  if(Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1) {
   character = character.toUpperCase();
  }
  code+= character;
 }
 return code;
}

console.log(generateCode(12));
```

Hopefully this is useful to you, although the passcode it generates may not be particularly secure as a password. The questions linked above have additional comments and responses which contain more resources and answers to your question. Their answers may generate passwords with more security and randomness.