# Generating password using Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, random

I have written a Python program to generate password. There is a glitch because it is not properly shuffled. Please suggest some methods to do it. Also suggest better methods for the same.

```
import random 
import array

digits = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
lowercase = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
uppercase = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
Symbols = ['!','@','#','$','%','*','&']

mixture = digits + lowercase + uppercase + Symbols

random_digit = random.choice(digits)
random_lowercase = random.choice(lowercase)
random_uppercase = random.choice(uppercase)
random_symbol = random.choice(Symbols) 

Password = random_digit + random_lowercase + random_uppercase + random_symbol

length = random.randint(8,12)

for x in range (length) :
    Password = Password + random.choice(mixture) 

print(Password)
```

Comment: I am a beginner in Python .

Comment: What's the issue here? What do you expect and what are you getting instead?

Comment: It is not shuffled properly .

Comment: I ran your code and generated `5uH%idWn!$aDQAT`. Can you explain how is this string not shuffled?

Comment: Well, you could do something like: randomize between 1 and 4 and then select either digit, case and symbol  and append to your password. But this is quite bad way of doing passwords.

Comment: The first 4 characters ..

Comment: Please suggest more standard approach to create password .

Comment: @Jarvis I think the issue might be that it's always digit-case-case -special  pattern.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479442/high-quality-simple-random-password-generator

Comment: For improvement, you don't need to list all the characters you want to use, the `string` module provides you with those characters. you could do `mixture = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation` and the result would be the same, kinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate your original `mixture` you can leverage the character sets available in `string`. Also note you don't need a list of individual chars, instead a single `str` is also an iterable sequence for this purpose.

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters as letters
>>> from string import digits as digits
>>> symbols = '!@#$%*&'
>>> mixture = digits + letters + symbols
>>> mixture
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%*&'
```

Then to generate some example passwords you can use `random.choices` with the `k` argument specifying the length to sample.

```
>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.choices(mixture, k=random.randint(8,12)))
'tF6iUwki1Ir'
>>> ''.join(random.choices(mixture, k=random.randint(8,12)))
'HpPJI6@m&'
>>> ''.join(random.choices(mixture, k=random.randint(8,12)))
'$KKzoiD&'
```

Note that `random.choices` allows duplicate characters, if you want them all to be unique then `random.sample` would be preferred.

Comment: You should be using `secrets` instead of the `random` for this purpose.
*In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.*
https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices

Comment: @Cory It is showing up module random has no attributes 'choices'.

Comment: @sshow Somebody might have programmed that too. So how it is that one will perform better than other?

Comment: @ShubhamKumar What version of Python are you using? `random.choices` is new to Python 3.6. Otherwise can do something like `''.join(random.choice(mixture) for _ in range(random.randint(8.12)))`

Answer (score 0):

I am just working on the method suggested by *Cory Kramer*.

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters
from string import digits as digits

symbols = '!@#$%&*'

mixture = digits + letters + symbols

import random
print('' .join(random.choice(mixture) for x in range (random.randint(8,12))))
```

Comment: Wow it is more crispier than my previous one.

Comment: you might want to use `random.shuffle` on the resulting list. 
 also https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html might be good to know about